# Decreasing rearrangement of trigonometric function(s)

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, decreasing-rearrangements

a) I am trying to find the decreasing rearrangement (DR) $f^*$ of the following function:
$$f(x)=\sin(2x)+\sin(x)+2$$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Admittedly, the $+2$ serves to get rid of negatives.

I learnt from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTcLmFYw3Zg) to derive that if $f(x)=\sin(x)$ then $f^*(x)=\cos(x/2).$ This was pretty much the only source I found (and could comprehend) so far. Thank you for suggestions.

b) In general, I would like to be able to find the DR of (pretty much) any sum of sinusoidal functions, such that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k \sin(2kx)+\sin(x)+n+1
$$
of which the above in (a) is the case for $n=1.$

I'm stuck, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the DR of function $f$ refer to?

Comment: Well, Decreasing Rearrangement; definition see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731216/distribution-function-and-decreasing-rearrangement

Comment: The definition itself (not just a link) belongs into your question, not into some comment.

Comment: Thanks; let $(X,dx)$ be a measure space and $f\in L^{p}(X,\mathbb{C})$; 
define its distribution function $F(\alpha)=meas({x\in X||f(x)|>\alpha})$
and the decreasing rearrangement $\alpha k=inf{\alpha>0|F(\alpha)<2k}$. Put in simpler (and probably less precise) words: "sort" all the values of $f$ decreasingly, thus getting a function "decreasing rearrangement" $f^*$ which has the same (local) maximum and minimum and integral in the interval in question. - Sorry for lack of lingo, not a professional at work.

Comment: The intent was that you add this definition to the question, not in another comment.

Comment: The definition depends on a finite measure on $\Bbb R$. What is this finite measure in your case?

Comment: Still nobody interested?